# selecting the first value that equals a number or letter sql php

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a db with 6 columns: `Taarij`, `Mispar` ,`Tiltan`, `Ale`, `Yaalom` and `Lev`.
I have a query that brings me the `50` last results ordered by `Mispar`, that works.

```
select * from Hagrala order by Mispar desc limit 0,50
```

I want from that query result to find some data.

For example I want to find the value of the field Mispar where `Ale = 7` the first time.
What I mean that `7` can and will appear several times in the column called `Ale`, but I am looking in which `Mispar` is the ***highest***.

If in a row `Mispar = 30765` and `Ale = 7` and in another row `Mispar = 30755` and `Ale=7` also I want to receive only 30765.

Comment: Use MySQL's aggregate functions such as `MAX()` and `COUNT()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select *
from Hagrala
where Ale = 7
order by Mispar desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: *"but I am looking in which Mispar is the highest."* - Therefore, `MAX()` should be used, correct? Or will your answer cover that?

Comment: What is the issue with sorting it in descending order?  That is an alternative way to get the maximum value.

Comment: Sure, I agree. But what if `Ale = 25` with an existing `7`? I know OP didn't state that, but am *just saying.* ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- . . . As I read the question, it is about the value "7".  If the OP wants the maximum `Mispar`, then s/he can remove the `where` clause.